# Internet Connectivity flutter

Tags: flutter, connection, internet-connection

This is the code i use to check for internet connectivity in flutter

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:internet_connection_checker/internet_connection_checker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CheckingConnectivity {
  late InternetConnectionChecker internetConnectionChecker;
  late StreamSubscription<InternetConnectionStatus> connectionStatusListener;
  bool hasInternetConnection = false;
  var onStatusChange = InternetConnectionChecker().onStatusChange;
  //Checking Internet connection
  internetChecker(BuildContext context) async {
    var connectionChanging = onStatusChange.listen((event) async {
      hasInternetConnection = event == InternetConnectionStatus.connected;

      if(hasInternetConnection == true) {
        showSnackBar(context, "Connected");
      } else if(hasInternetConnection == false) {
        showSnackBar(context, "Disconnected");
      } 
    });
  }
  showSnackBar(BuildContext context, String message) {
    final snackBar = SnackBar(content:  Text(message,
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, backgroundColor: Colors.grey),));
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }
}
```

When the application launches, it shows connected even when i am already connected to the internet. I want it to show connected only when i reconnect to the internet. Thank you very much. I appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, when looking through the library's code, I see that they initially always send a status update. A simple workaround would be to have a counter variable that increments every time you receive a status change event. If the counter variable has its default value, you know you received the initial event.

Comment: Thanks but i'm a newbie to flutter. Can you help me with the code for it?

Comment: Sure. In your class create a int variable called counter or something similar with the value 0. The line before hasInternetConnection you increment this counter variable by one. After incrementing it, you check if the value this counter equals to 1. If this is true, simply return, which "ignores" the event.